# Proving the trigonometric identity $\tan 2\theta + \sin 2\theta = \frac{2\sin 2\theta}{1 - \tan^2\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

Today I have to prove a trig identity.

It involves double angle.
$$\tan 2\theta + \sin 2\theta = \frac{2\sin 2\theta}{1 - \tan^2\theta}$$

Comment: So... where are you stuck?

Comment: The Whole Problem Stuck o me

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan2y+\sin2y=\sin2y\cdot\dfrac{1+\cos2y}{\cos2y}$$

Now use $\cos2y=\dfrac{1-\tan^2y}{1+\tan^2y}$